# How to enable Ookla script to start automatically after server reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed Ookla speed test on my server. Everything is working but I don't know how to enable Ookla script to start automatically after the server reboot.I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I already checked Ookla website(https://support.ookla.com/hc/en-us/articles/234578588-Linux-Startup-Script-Options) but did understand it properly. They said I need to enable the script on /etc/rc.local
I also did not find rc.local on /etc. How can I enable the script to start automatically? I am new on Linux.

Comment: Please also share which Linux you are using. This will help people to provide precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my unit file for ookla speedtest service:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/speedtest.service
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ookla-user
Group=nogroup

WorkingDirectory=/opt/ooklaserver/

Type=simple
KillMode=mixed

ExecStart=/opt/ooklaserver/OoklaServer

TimeoutStartSec=30
TimeoutStopSec=60

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save it into the `/etc/systemd/system/speedtest.service` file. Then run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl enable speedtest.service`.

Answer (score 0):

let me help you a little bit, this worked for me (KillMode=process):

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ookla-user
Group=nogroup

WorkingDirectory=/home/ookla-user

Type=forking
KillMode=process

ExecStart=/home/ookla-user/ooklaserver.sh start

TimeoutStartSec=30
TimeoutStopSec=60

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```